# Triggering modal from condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have been painfully attempting to try and trigger a modal to fire, when a user writes more than 10 words in a textarea. I have tried the bootstrap documentation, 'Toggle AND 'Show' but they don't work. My console informs me that '.modal' isn't a correct function? but bootstrap informs me it is!

Basically my modal does not fire when the condition is met.

Here is my code:

```
HTML

  <form>
  <textarea placeholder="Would you like to leave a review?" maxlength="" id="textareaID"></textarea>
</form>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

JS

```
$('#textareaID').bind('input propertychange', function() {
  if (this.value.length > 10) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle');
  }
    $("#textareaID").val($("#textareaID").val().substring(0,20));
}
});
```

Comment: 10 words? You mean 10 characters, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.modal('show')` with proper syntax and it's working. It will display modal as soon as you enter 11th character. You can change the condition as per your need.

Regarding the use of `$(document).ready()`, you should wrap most javascript stuff in this function rather than using it in the `if` condition. It is just as a best practices. Not all elements would be available when the javascript is being executed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#textareaID').on('input propertychange', function() {
    if (this.value.length > 10) {
      $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
      $("#textareaID").val($("#textareaID").val().substring(0, 20));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form>
  <textarea placeholder="Would you like to leave a review?" maxlength="" id="textareaID"></textarea>
</form>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `.modal('show')`.

Keep in mind that adding `$(document).ready(fun...` inside the binding is useless. You should be wrapping all your jQuery inside it.

Use the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#textareaID').on('input propertychange', function() {
    if ($('#textareaID').val().length > 10) {
      $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
      $("#textareaID").val($("#textareaID").val().substring(0,20));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"><form>
  <textarea placeholder="Would you like to leave a review?" maxlength="" id="textareaID"></textarea>
</form>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```